# Is this false solution?

Tags: numerical-value

I tried W.A to find the solution for $log(-i)$ and the result is $log(-i) = -i\pi/2$ . But I calculate 'by hand' that $e^{-i\pi/2} = i   ?$ . Is this result / solution false ?

Comment: $e^{-i\pi/2}$ = $(e^{i\pi})^{-1/2} = (-1)^{-1/2} = i$ ?

Comment: Here 'log' is natural log.

Comment: Your calculations "by hand" are wrong: `Exp[-I \[Pi]/2] = Cos[-\[Pi]/2] + I Sin[-\[Pi]/2] = -I`.

Comment: Which part is wrong ?

Comment: In MMA `(-1)^(-1/2) = 1/I =  -I`, but I showed general way to deal with "imaginary" exponents.

Comment: But is it $(-1)^{-1/2} = (1/-1)^{1/2}$  ?

Comment: `(-1)^(-1/2) = 1/(-1)^(1/2) = 1/I = -I`.

Comment: LIke this $(2)^{-1/2} = (1/2)^{1/2} $

Comment: Check with Mathematica `Reduce[x^(-n) == (1/x)^(n)]` and `Reduce[x^(-n) == (1/(x^n))]`, I'm tired, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

W.A. is correct. Let $z=-i$, then $z=r e^{i \arg(z)}$ then
$$
        \ln(z) = \ln|r| + i \arg(z)
$$

But $|r|=|-i|=1$ and $\arg(z) = \arg(-i) = \frac{-\pi}{2}$ (clock wise is negative). Hence

\begin{align*}
        \ln(-i) &= \ln(1) - i \frac{\pi}{2}\\
               &=  0 -i \frac{\pi}{2}\\
               &= -i \frac{\pi}{2}\\
\end{align*}

Comment: Do you see my calculation 'by hand' at comment ? . The result is i and not -i  .

Comment: See my comment, they are wrong.

Comment: @Alx Could you show me the wrong part ?

Comment: conjugation of i  ?